# Create column type Datetime in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

What is the proper way to create column type Datetime in MariaDB using Hibernate? I tried this:

```
@Column
@Type(type = "date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date created_at;
```

But I can't find a proper type in TemporalType for Datetime.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use TemporalType.TIMESTAMP for DateTime.

Comment: Can I use `private DateTime startTime;`?

Comment: You should be able to. Any specific reason you want to use DateTime? java.util.Date do have timestamp component.

Comment: By `DateTime` do you mean the one from Joda Time? You're better off switching to Java 8's `LocalDateTime` class, which is supported since Hibernate 5.0 with an additional module dependency and since 5.2 it's built-in.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do.

```
@Column
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created_at;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  to write `@Type(type = "date")`. And change your `TemporalType` to `TimeStamp` . So finally your code will be like this;

```
@Column
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created_at;
```

**PS:** You don't need to write `@Column` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use the columnDefinition attribute of the @Column annotation:

```
@Column(name = "startTime", columnDefinition="DATETIME")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startTime;
```

Comment: Ok but can I use `private DateTime startTime;`?

Comment: @Peter Penzov Can you try doing that?

Comment: yes.create getter and setter for outside class use.